# Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\React.js

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
X [ERROR] Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\React.js

E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1596
  let error = new Error(`${text}${summary}`);
              ^

Error: Build failed with 1 error:
error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\React.js
    at failureErrorWithLog (E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1596:15)
    at E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1052:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1468:61)
    at buildResponseToResult (E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1050:7)
    at E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1162:14
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:697:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:752:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (E:\DGSfrontend\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:673:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: null,
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\\.vite\\deps_temp\\React.js'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

tried checking and rechecking the file name and package names but didn't work.it occured after I started routing with react-router-dom. It worked before but after some time the error stopped the build and stopped the site